# Issuing a refund using a 3rd-party eCommerce tool, PayPal Payflow Pro and MS CRM

Tags: paypal, dynamics-crm-2011, integration

I am collecting financial transactions via a third-party eCommerce site/application.  I am passing records/details of those transactions to MS Dynamics CRM.  To process the payments, we are using PayPal Payflow Pro.  Unfortunately, the third-party eCommerce tool does not issue refunds from its application.

Is there a way to build an integration within MS Dynamics CRM that would process the refund/issue credit (i.e., send information back to PayPal)???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that the third-party eCommerce site/application is using your PayPal account and providing you the the `PaymentId`.

PayPal Payflow Pro has a [developer's guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/) that document's their RESTful API.

You need to look at the [refund documentation and code example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#refund-a-sale).

In your CRM Plugin (you'll need someone with the ability to write a plugin or custom workflow) project use NuGet to install the Paypal library: `Install-Package Paypal`. You'll need to make this available to the plugin DLL either on disk, via the GAC, or (preferably) by merging using ILMerge ([see my blog post](http://nicknow.net/dynamics-crm-ilmerge-dll-plugin/).)

```
 OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential =
   new OAuthTokenCredential("<CLIENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>");

 string accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();

 Sale sale = Sale.Get(accessToken, "2MU78835H4515710F");

 Amount amount = new Amount();
 amount.total = "2.34";
 amount.currency = "USD";

 Refund refund = new Refund();
 refund.amount = amount;

 Refund newRefund = sale.Refund(accessToken, refund);
```

Store your client id and client secret values in a configuration entity. Also, be sure to have a custom refund entity to store the fields in `newRefund`.